# Using avconv (ffmpeg) to concatenate a bunch of .bmps into a mkv/avi video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, bmp, libav

Trying to figure out how to get avconv to concatenate a bunch of .bmps together into a video file.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
avconv -f image2 -i Capture/%d.bmp -vcodec mpeg4 -r 24 -b:v 20M Capture.mkv
```

While this does work, the quality is terrible - there are tons of artifacts that are visible, the colours are distorted and everything is blurred.

I've trawled through the documentation for `avconv` and `ffmpeg`, but can't find anything that increases the quality.

Any ideas as to how I can get the quality as close to the original bmps as possible?

Comment: I haven't even been able to get this to work... The command I'm using appears to overwrite the original bitmap: Same command as yours except I am using `-i output_{0..1023}.bmp`

Answer (score 4):

```
-vcodec mpeg4
```

That could be your problem. MPEG-4 is a fairly good codec, but it's easily outperformed by h.264 – x264 being a popular example for an h.264 encoder. I'm not sure how big of a role the bitrate plays here, but it would help to just try x264. Therefore, use

```
-c:v libx264
```

to change your encoder.* In order to tune the quality, set the [Constant Rate Factor](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/crf.html) to a level of your choice. Sane values are from 19 to 24, where lower values mean better quality.

```
avconv -f image2 -i Capture/%d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 24 -crf 21 Capture.mkv
```

If you still see artifacts, you might want to give us more info, and update your post with the full, uncut console output from your `avconv` command.

<sub>* `-c:v` is the new syntax used instead of `vcodec`, similar to `-b:v`. Try to keep sticking to that.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To get the best match to your BMP, I suggest doing what I did: convert to TIF or JPEG since avconv doesn't handle BMP very nicely - no matter many high quality settings I discovered and set.

A visual way to do this is simply get GIMP and BIMP (which is an excellent batch program anyway) and do a batch conversion of your BMPs to JPEGs at 100% quality or TIF (you could use TIF compression).

Now try the same avconv action. I used `avconv -f image2 -r 15 -i animation%04d.jpg -r:v 15 -c:v h264 -crf 1 -an "animation_test.mov"` but it should be fine with your mkv action now.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a different video codec. It might only work in QuickTime files (not Matroska), but `qtrle` is a lossless video codec, although it doesn't compress very well.